# I'm trying to vary the power sent to a heating element based on the heat in an enclosure

Tags: relay, solid-state-relay, pid-controller, heater

I'm building an enclosure for my 3d printer and I was considering using just a ceramic air heater and a fan to control the temperature in the enclosure. I have some misgivings about this however. For example, my setup would be to have an SSR that is controlled by the 3d printer's mainboard that connects my 110V wall outlet to the 1500W air heater. I would rather have it to where it can send variable power to the heater to compensate for the heat drop in the enclosure. Similar to feedback/PID control. Is there an electrical component that I could use for this? From my research on relays they can only be open or closed, so they wouldn't work for my application.

Comment: The thing about heat is it takes a really long time for things to warm up or cool down so it just doesn't make sense to bother with a variable heat level. You have 100 or 120 chances per second to turn the heater fully on or fully off. If you really do want continuous variability, you could probably do something similar to a lightbulb dimmer.

Comment: @user253751 that makes sense. My only concern is the constant powering on and powering off of the heater all the time. Is this a concern or is it not going to be a problem?

Comment: plenty of real heaters switch themselves on or off every few seconds. I have an electric stove which does this.

Comment: Notice the heater won't heat up and cool down really quickly, because it takes a while to heat up and cool down, so it's not like it's a huge thermal stress.

Comment: How large is this enclosure? That’s a lot of heat.

Comment: What is your tolerance on the temperature regulation? A simple on/off controller with deadband will vary a few degrees.

Comment: on-off switching is the usual method for temperature control